# Feature Extraction for timeseries temperature signal

Tags: python, time-series, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

i have two temperature signals from which one is sensitive toward a specific event. I would like to know what other features can be useful to extract apart from:

1. Angles (between the two).
2. Slopes ( between the two).

P.S. Language is Python

Answer (score 1):

- **Cross correlation**
  A high cross-correlation value indicates a strong correlation between the two signals, which can be useful for identifying the specific event that one of the signals is sensitive to.
- **TimeLag**
  Which represents the time delay between the occurrence of the event in one signal and its effect on the other signal.
- **Frequency** **Analysis**
  This can be useful for identifying any periodicities or cycles in the signals that may be related to the specific event.
- **Statistical** **Analysis**
  You can perform various statistical analyses of the two signals, such as mean, median, variance, and standard deviation, to compare their overall characteristics.